Debugging auto scrolling custom carousel in React
I'm trying to create a carousel in React, and build is working perfectly. I am passing a json array of 4 objects. And I expect the carousel to work as below.
show slides 1,2,3 - 2,3,4 - 3,4,1, - 4,1,2 and so on in a circular loop. But currently I see, 1,2,3 - 3,4 - 1 - Blank - 1,2,3.
Not sure of where I'm going wrong.
Here is my slider code.
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Slider = ({
  sliderData,
  autoScroll = true,
  intervalTime = 3000,
  visibleSlides = 3,
}: any) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const intervalRef = useRef<number | null>(null);
  const slideWidth = 100 / visibleSlides;
  const slideStyle = {
    transform: `translateX(-${currentIndex * slideWidth}%)`,
    transition: "transform 0.5s ease-in-out",
  };
  const next = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((current) => (current + 1) % sliderData.length);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (autoScroll) {
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(next, intervalTime);
    }

    return () => {
      if (intervalRef.current) clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    };
  }, [autoScroll, intervalTime]);

  const endIndex = currentIndex + visibleSlides;
  const visibleServices = [];
  for (let i = currentIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
    visibleServices.push(sliderData[i % sliderData.length]);
  }

  return (
    <section
      aria-labelledby="services-heading"
      className={`overflow-hidden relative max-w-screen-xl  mx-auto `}
    >
      <h1 id="services-heading" className="sr-only">
        Our Services
      </h1>
      <div className="flex " style={slideStyle}>
        {visibleServices.map((service, index) => (
          <article
            key={index}
            className="bg-white border [&:not(:first-child)]:ml-8 flex flex-col gap-4 pb-6 h-auto w-[490px]"
          >
            <h3 className="px-4 text-xl font-bold ">{service.name}</h3>
            <p className=" px-4">{service.c_serviceDescription}</p>
          </article>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
export default Slider;

Where am I going wrong? Here is my fully working fiddle. Here is my output image:

